# Replace front wheel studs '99 saturn

Tags: wheels, saturn

I'm trying to replace front wheel studs on a '99 saturn w/o removing the hub.  I got the old ones out, but for the life of me can't seem to get the new ones in securely.   I attempted pressing them in with a C-clamp positioned with one side on the back of the new stud and the other side on a socket placed over the bolt, i.e. to pull the bolt into position with clamp.  That broke the clamp.  Any other suggestions?

And if it comes to the point where I must remove the hub, any pointers?

Comment: Mine needed to get pressed in or with an hammer, not sure I would have been able to this without removing the brake rotor, in my case, and part of the hub. Maybe someone more Saturn knowledgeable could confirm.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up pulling them through by tightening an old lug nut onto the new stud with a spacer between the nut and the hub using this technique: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XX9te2iFH3E except with with a regular lug wrench instead of an impact wrench.   Well actually my dad did since he came over prepared to help me remove the hub.  Drove on it this morning and it seems fine.  I'll check later today to make sure everything is still together tight.

Although from this video, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z7RnZnnI56M&feature=related, I wasn't too far off with the clamp approach.  I just didn't have a heavy enough clamp.

Just to clarify, you should definitely remove the caliper and rotor.

Comment: In the second video, it's looks like a power clamp! Looks easy enough. Make sure your stud head is well seated and enjoy!